# Error APIRemovedInV1 when trying to ask a chatbot with memory

Tags: python, openai-api, streamlit, py-langchain, openaiembeddings

Im trying to make a chatbot with memory to keep the context of the conversation using some functions from the langchain library using python and streamlit to make it a web page but when i try to ask it some questions, it gives this error:

```
APIRemovedInV1: You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API. You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface. Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28` A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\Documents\preguntapdf\app3.py", line 211, in <module>
    res = agent_chain.invoke(query)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 162, in invoke
    raise e
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 156, in invoke
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1371, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1097, in _take_next_step
    [
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1097, in <listcomp>
    [
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1125, in _iter_next_step
    output = self.agent.plan(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 694, in plan
    full_output = self.llm_chain.predict(callbacks=callbacks, **full_inputs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\llm.py", line 293, in predict
    return self(kwargs, callbacks=callbacks)[self.output_key]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\_api\deprecation.py", line 145, in warning_emitting_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 363, in __call__
    return self.invoke(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 162, in invoke
    raise e
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 156, in invoke
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\llm.py", line 103, in _call
    response = self.generate([inputs], run_manager=run_manager)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\llm.py", line 115, in generate
    return self.llm.generate_prompt(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 525, in generate_prompt
    return self.generate(prompt_strings, stop=stop, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 698, in generate
    output = self._generate_helper(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 562, in _generate_helper
    raise e
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 549, in _generate_helper
    self._generate(
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\llms\openai.py", line 1158, in _generate
    full_response = completion_with_retry(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\llms\openai.py", line 115, in completion_with_retry
    return llm.client.create(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\JBERROCAL\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openai\lib\_old_api.py", line 39, in __call__
    raise APIRemovedInV1(symbol=self._symbol)
```

Im not using that method in my code and the error points to a langchain function so i dont know how to change it, i tried downgrading to openai 0.28 like the error says but then it doesnt recognize my api key, anyone knows what to do?

Here is the full code:

```
# Import necessary modules
import re
import time
from io import BytesIO
from typing import Any, Dict, List

import openai
import streamlit as st
from langchain import LLMChain, OpenAI
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, Tool, ZeroShotAgent
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import VectorStore
from langchain.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
from pypdf import PdfReader


hide_st_style = """
            <style>
            #MainMenu {visibility: hidden;}
            footer {visibility: hidden;}
            header {visibility: hidden;}
            </style>
            """
st.markdown(hide_st_style, unsafe_allow_html=True)


# Define a function to parse a PDF file and extract its text content
def parse_pdf(file: BytesIO) -> List[str]:
    pdf = PdfReader(file)
    output = []
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        # Merge hyphenated words
        text = re.sub(r"(\w+)-\n(\w+)", r"\1\2", text)
        # Fix newlines in the middle of sentences
        text = re.sub(r"(?<!\n\s)\n(?!\s\n)", " ", text.strip())
        # Remove multiple newlines
        text = re.sub(r"\n\s*\n", "\n\n", text)
        output.append(text)
    return output


# Define a function to convert text content to a list of documents
def text_to_docs(text: str) -> List[Document]:
    """Converts a string or list of strings to a list of Documents
    with metadata."""
    if isinstance(text, str):
        # Take a single string as one page
        text = [text]
    page_docs = [Document(page_content=page) for page in text]

    # Add page numbers as metadata
    for i, doc in enumerate(page_docs):
        doc.metadata["page"] = i + 1

    # Split pages into chunks
    doc_chunks = []

    for doc in page_docs:
        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
            chunk_size=4000,
            separators=["\n\n", "\n", ".", "!", "?", ",", " ", ""],
            chunk_overlap=0,
        )
        chunks = text_splitter.split_text(doc.page_content)
        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            doc = Document(
                page_content=chunk, metadata={"page": doc.metadata["page"], "chunk": i}
            )
            # Add sources a metadata
            doc.metadata["source"] = f"{doc.metadata['page']}-{doc.metadata['chunk']}"
            doc_chunks.append(doc)
    return doc_chunks


# Define a function for the embeddings
def test_embed():
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=api)
    # Indexing
    # Save in a Vector DB
    with st.spinner("It's indexing..."):
        index = FAISS.from_documents(pages, embeddings)
    st.success("Embeddings done.", icon="✅")
    return index


# Set up the Streamlit app
st.title(" Personalized Bot with Memory  ")

# Set up the sidebar
st.sidebar.markdown(
    """
    ### Steps:
    1. Upload PDF File
    2. Enter Your Secret Key for Embeddings
    3. Perform Q&A

    **Note : File content and API key not stored in any form.**
    """
)

# Allow the user to upload a PDF file
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader(
    "**Upload Your PDF File**",
    type=["pdf"],
)

if uploaded_file:
    name_of_file = uploaded_file.name
    doc = parse_pdf(uploaded_file)
    pages = text_to_docs(doc)
    if pages:
        # Allow the user to select a page and view its content
        with st.expander("Show Page Content", expanded=False):
            page_sel = st.number_input(
                label="Select Page", min_value=1, max_value=len(pages), step=1
            )
            pages[page_sel - 1]
        # Allow the user to enter an OpenAI API key
        api = st.text_input(
            "**Enter OpenAI API Key**",
            type="password",
            placeholder="sk-",
            help="https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys",
        )
        if api:
            # Test the embeddings and save the index in a vector database
            index = test_embed()
            # Set up the question-answering system
            qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
                llm=OpenAI(openai_api_key=api),
                chain_type="stuff",
                retriever=index.as_retriever(),
            )
            # Set up the conversational agent
            tools = [
                Tool(
                    name="State of Union QA System",
                    func=qa.run,
                    description="Useful for when you need to answer questions about the aspects asked. Input may be a partial or fully formed question.",
                )
            ]
            prefix = """Have a conversation with a human, answering the following questions as best you can based on the context and memory available. 
                        You have access to a single tool:"""
            suffix = """Begin!"

            {chat_history}
            Question: {input}
            {agent_scratchpad}"""

            prompt = ZeroShotAgent.create_prompt(
                tools,
                prefix=prefix,
                suffix=suffix,
                input_variables=["input", "chat_history", "agent_scratchpad"],
            )

            if "memory" not in st.session_state:
                st.session_state.memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
                    memory_key="chat_history"
                )

            llm_chain = LLMChain(
                llm=OpenAI(
                    temperature=0, openai_api_key=api, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo"
                ),
                prompt=prompt,
            )
            agent = ZeroShotAgent(llm_chain=llm_chain, tools=tools, verbose=True)
            agent_chain = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
                agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True, memory=st.session_state.memory
            )

            # Allow the user to enter a query and generate a response
            query = st.text_input(
                "**What's on your mind?**",
                placeholder="Ask me anything from {}".format(name_of_file),
            )

            if query:
                with st.spinner(
                    "Generating Answer to your Query : `{}` ".format(query)
                ):
                    res = agent_chain.invoke(query)
                    st.info(res, icon="")

            # Allow the user to view the conversation history and other information stored in the agent's memory
            with st.expander("History/Memory"):
                st.session_state.memory
```